# RMAN Control File Information

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, rman

I have daily full backups going on for my Oracle 12c databases on linux. Daily retention on disk is 6 days.

This is what happens:

Full backup happens at location

> /orcl_bkup/backup_full

After each day's full backup gets over, I make sure that the above mentioned path only contains that day's backup pieces in that path and the older backups will be moved to another folder

> /orcl_bkup/old_bkup

The reason for the above mentioned movement of backup pieces is necessary for my OS team for some activity at their end.

My question is that, in this scenario, will my control file lose the information of older backups? Do I need to do *catalog start with the /orcl_bkup/old_bkup* and *catalog the backup location* to delete the obsolete backups?

Comment: You'd be better off symbolic linking them from the other folder, rather than actually moving them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to catalog the backups at their new location.

You should run crosscheck also on the backups, so the entries pointing to the old location become EXPIRED.